# How to center canvas in GIMP

Tags: gimp

When I create a new document in GIMP, the default canvas is not centered and is aligned to top:
[image]

This creates problems because, if by a slight mistake I go above the canvas, the menus are clicked accidentally. This is awkward. 
I want to center the canvas.

I have tried in preferences but I found no relevant option there.

I tried view>>Navigation; clicking one of the bottom buttons enlarges it but there is no option to center the canvas. How can I center the canvas 
for example in this video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzYdQE1Tbyw
(Please ignore the contents of the video and its title. I am talking about the way canvas is displayed in his GIMP window.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can hold the `Space`-key and move the canvas with your mouse. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-J</kbd> followed by <kbd>1</kbd> will center the image in the canvas.

But I'm surprised your Gimp work that way, when I open an image in Gimp it is centered in the canvas.